# Colors, label in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, enumerate

`X` is a 100x2 vector that contains sepal and pethal length data for 2 kinds of flowers. `y` is a 100x1 vector that contains label values for my data: -1 and 1. I create a meshgrid, then I plotted my meshgrid using `countourf` method and now I load the data in the meshgrid with this code:

```
for idx, cl in enumerate (np.unique(y)):
    plt.scatter (x=X[y == cl, 0], y= X[y == cl, 1], alpha=0.8, c=colors[idx], marker= markers [idx], label = cl, edgecolor = 'black')
```

`alpha, colors, marker, edgecolor` are just secondary things. Also `np.unique(y) = [-1 1]` .

My question is, Why `[y==cl,0]` is a false and `[y==,1]` is a true argument? and, How using `==` can I classifier my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for loop, `cl` loops over the two *unique* values of `y` i.e. `[-1, 1]`. So in the first loop iteration, `cl=-1` and `y == cl` returns the rows where your y values are -1. Therefore, `[y == cl, 0]` returns the locations where y is -1 and the data is the first column (index 0) which is Sepal length. Similarly, `[y == cl, 1]` returns the locations where y is -1 and the data is the second column (index 1) which is Petal length.

The same applies in the second iteration of the loop when `cl` is 1.